# Where does my NullPointerException come from?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm currently having a problem with my app whereby occassionally users are clicking on one of my options and being presented with a NullPointerException. The problem being, the error reports contain no information and I can't figure out why it happens. This is the stack trace submitted:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.espian.formulae.ListMenu.thermoItemClick(ListMenu.java:754)
at com.espian.formulae.ListMenu$2.onItemClick(ListMenu.java:386)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3672)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1829)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

and this is the offending method:

```
protected void thermoItemClick(int position) {

    Intent i = new Intent();
    TextView t = (TextView)lv.getChildAt(position);

    switch (position) {
        case 0: //Thermo functions
            i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Tab_Hoster.class);
            i.putExtra(Tab_Hoster.EXTRA, Tab_Hoster.TAB_THERMO);
            break;
        case 1: //C-C equation
        case 2: // C equation
        case 3: //vant hoff
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
            i.setClass(getApplicationContext(), Equation.class);
            break;
        default:
            i = null;
    }
    if (i != null) {
        String s = (String) t.getText();
        i.putExtra(States.KEY_E, s);
        i.putExtra(States.TABLE, States.EQUATION);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    if (cleanscreen)
        this.finish();
}
```

If it helps, it seems to this normally seems to occur only the first time people select this option and tends to be fine after that. I've had no occurrences of this exception myself, and I've only had 14 reports of it but it's annoying and I'd like to get to the bottom of it.

Thanks

Comment: Which one of these line is 754?

Comment: not the answer to your problem, but you may want to explicitly `break;` from your `default:` in the `switch`

Comment: Only thing I can see that could cause that would be `TextView t = (TextView)lv.getChildAt(position);`

Comment: I'm afraid I've changed my code significantly since the last error report so I can't tell which 754 is, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `TextView t = (TextView)lv.getChildAt(position);` is incorrectly called (i.e., lv doesn't include any View in this position) then t will be null and `t.getText()` will throw an exception.

In General I recommend to avoid loading Views using ViewGroup.getChildAt(). it's just not safe. I'm guessing you dynamically build a layout, that's why you can't findViewById this TextView.
What I do in cases like these, when I dynamically build layouts, I also allocate IDs to these layouts (store them in a map or something in memory) and then using the very-safe findViewById method.

Comment: Cool thanks. I thought this way was a little fudgy but I wasn't really sure how else to do it- this is a `Listview` populated from a `StringArray`, so how would I go about allocating IDs to them?

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that your position variable is not matching any of those cases. Also try different versions of the emulator, could be version specific.

Answer (score 0):

Since it only happens the first time then something is most likely not initialized.  Where does the variable `cleanscreen` come from?  Is it a global variable?  Is it initialized during onCreate, or when it is declared?

Most likely the textview is empty.  If t is empty (null) then

`String s = (String) t.getText()`

will be null.

Comment: cleanscreen is initialised in `onCreate` from a `SharedPreferences` and t shouldn't really be null because this is created from a `ListView` populated using a String array. People can obviously see the labels for each selection, but the get the NPE when they click on them?